# Desktop connection to MySQL in Amazon EC2 using C# (How To)

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-ec2

In my desktop application I need to connect to MySQL database in Amazon EC2. I tried to built the connection string but am very confused as to what parameters I need to include and how the connection string should look like and what commands need to call. Can anyone experience in this provide me with sample listings so that I can follow? Your help is very much appreciated.

Information I have on EC2 which I use to connect successfully using Workbench:

- SSH Hostname
- SSH Username
- SSH Key File (reside in my PC)
- MySQL Hostname (ie 127.0.0.1)
- MySQL Server Port (ie 3306)
- Userpassword

Answer (score 1):

After some research over the internet, I have found the answer to this seemingly simple question.
All I need to do really is add in MySQL /net connector in the project and referenced it.
Then I used the follwoing connecting string:-

eg: 
    myConnStr = "host=ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com" +
    ";Port=3306;UserName=your_db_username" +
    ";Password=your_db_password;Database=your_db;";

Thanks!